# ADF Dynamic Expression - concat/if missing period

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

In what I would have thought was relatively simple code, I can't figure out what the issue is with adding another string to my list of concatenations

Below is the code that I currently have and I get expected output

`@concat('start ', if(equals(coalesce(pipeline().parameters.p_source_object.TYPE,''),'x'), 'a', 'b'))`

However, I want to add more strings to the concatenation but when I add a comma between the two end brackets like so

`@concat('start ', if(equals(coalesce(pipeline().parameters.p_source_object.TYPE,''),'x'), 'a', 'b'), )`

I get an "Invalid" error with "Missing period" message. If I put a period before the comma, the error goes away (but obviously invalid syntax)

What is it expecting here?

On a related note, is there a better way to concatenate while also doing some functions that output strings? It's the most unintuitive interface imaginable (Microsoft do seem to pride themselves in the ridiculous!)

Hoping someone can find my sanity for me!

Comment: I'm not sure about the "missing period", I've never seen that before. Can you post a screen shot? For more complex operations like this, I often break it down into multiple variables just because it can be so hard to visually parse. [This is especially true when your output string contains quotes and commas!] So I would take any function level assignment (like the if in your example) and place that in its own variable. The concat will be much easier to construct at that point: @concat('start ', variables('someVar'), variables('someOtherVar')).

Comment: Will do when I'm back on it, however, as for your comment about the variables, I was debating that way but I have a few of these "ifs" to compose the full string I require and with the inane way of setting variables, it will make quite a train - unless I've missed a better way of setting variables?

Comment: @RAB concat() function must set parameter after period  ',' the parameter can not be null. The function like  `concat('a',)` is Invalid.

Comment: @LeonYue, I think you're reading the issue the wrong way around, I cannot enter another parameter at all because it is expecting a period (note, period is "." rather than ",")

Comment: @RAB : I think the parameter with the "."  is the issue . Can you just try to use a setvariable activity and try to assign the parameter to a varibale , when i tested it failed .

Answer (score 3):

In the end, I completely reworked it avoiding the layers... however, I have discovered a resolution

`@{concat('start ', if(equals(coalesce(pipeline().parameters.p_source_object.TYPE,''),'x'), 'a', 'b'), 'dd')}`

While it doesn't stand out as to how... there's a space at the start of the line, this stops it being considered "Dynamic content" but instead uses string interpolation

Comment: and in fact... just the squiggly brackets appears to actually do the trick!